# Review Lists showing incorrect total

Tags: bug

[image: Review Lists]

On the review tab I noticed the total next to each option to review.  Then when you actually click on one, surprisingly it would be empty.

[image: Review First Answers]

It took me a few moments to figure out that this was because it was on the day setting.  To actual match the total you would have to click the "all" button.  Essentially what I am saying is that this behavior is unexpected and maybe a more intuitive way of doing it would be to send the user to the page with "all" selected, therefor you wouldn't default them to seeing 0 posts.